# Python - What's wrong with my socket code

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a simple Python program I am currently developing and for some reason, it won't work.
The way the full program works is it has a list of 20 ports and it then loops through that list basically pinging the host on the selected port. Here's the code:

```
import socket
import sys

print '  +-====================================================-+'
print ' /                                                        \ '
print '|                       PyPortScanner                      |'
print '|                       by Ag3ntChr0m                      |'
print ' \                                                        /'
print '  +-====================================================-+'
print ''

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + 'Error message: ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
print 'Socket Created'

host = raw_input('Enter the desired host to scan: ')
port = [80, 443, 21, 22, 4567, 8080, 25, 3389, 23, 53, 1723, 110, 135, 445,
        139, 1863, 143, 8081, 10000, 1025]
portFail = []
print 'Scanning top 20 most often open ports ...'

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:
    #couldn't resolve host at port
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Program exiting'
    sys.exit()

print 'IP address of ' + host + ' is ' + remote_ip

print '+-===================================-+'
print '| Ports Scanned:----------------------|'
print '+-===================================-+'
print ''

#Connect to remote server
for i in range(0, 20):
    portScan = int(str(port[i]))    <----
    try:

        s.connect((remote_ip, portScan))
        print "\t" + str(portScan)
        s.close()

    except:

        portFail.append(portScan)
        err = True

raw_input('Press Enter to Continue...')

if err:
    print '+-=============================-+'
    print '| Failed Port Scan:-------------|'
    print '+-=============================-+'
    print ''
    size = len(portFail)
    for i in range(1, size):
        print "\t" + str(portFail[i])
```

When you run the program it then is supposed to

- load (at the line marked by the arrow) the port number into a variable the s.socket can use to attempt a connection.
- It then attempts to open a socket on the host (basically ping it) and then close it.
- If it connects it writes this on the screen under Ports Scanned.
- However, if it fails (and it has been lately) it gets printed under Failed Port Scan.

When I go to run the program it prints the first port on the list (80) under Ports Scanned, but the rest get placed under Failed Port Scan - even though I know at least some of they are open.

How would I get this program ping more ports than the first successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the answer from @cnicutar you can't reuse the `socket`. But you also should `close()` the socket after use in all cases as this will release the underlying resources. This can also be seen in the examples found in the [api documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown).

When you are successfull at connecting to a port you should call `shutdown()` afterwards to ensure that it is closed.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
for portScan in port:
    try:
        print "scanning: %s" % portScan 
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((remote_ip, portScan))
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    except:
        portFail.append(portScan)
        err = True
    finally:
        s.close()
```

I also took the liberty to simplify the loop.

NOTE: My experiment showed that `shutdown()` did not allow me to reuse the `socket`.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to work! Though don't try going after google, it freezes it up bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just reuse the same socket and connect again. Try making a new socket each time:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((remote_ip, portScan))
```

Even if you `close` a socket, that doesn't put it back into a position where it can be reconnected.

Comment: Wouldn't `close()` or `shutdown()` do that?

Comment: @user2176286 In the time it took you to write this comment you could have easily tested what I posted.

Comment: I did and it froze up IDLE and the IDLE Python Shell...?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @cnicutar, you cannot reuse a socket, but you always can start a new socket for every new connection.
You should use a for loop for scanning the ports, something like:

```
for p2scan in port:
    try:
        print "scanning: %s" % p2scan
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((remote_ip, p2scan))
    except:
        portFail.append(p2scan)
        err = True
    finally:
        s.close()
```